# Title/author of a novella about three youths who meld and oppose an unseen adult, pre-1973?

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for the title/author of a novella written at least before 1973.

- The story revolves around three youths (teens?) who "meld"?? Melding is some sort of process that the beings of the story partake in, and requires two 'males' and one 'female'.
- These youths are in conflict with their adults, specifically around a particular adult whom they have never seen. This adult is working on some project which these teens are opposed to.
- I think it was a novella and either won or was nominated for an award (although maybe not).
- Great twist at the end around the youths, melding, etc.!

Comment: Not your answer, but more than passing similarities with 2nd part of The Gods Themselves (Asimov), if you replace human teens with alien adolescents.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95471/story-about-machines-generating-energy-with-parallel-universes-endangering-ours (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 13):

This may be [Isaac Asimov's The Gods Themselves](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41821.The_Gods_Themselves)

[image: cover-1] [image: cover-2] [image: cover-3]

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gods_Themselves):

> The second part takes place in the parallel universe, whose
>   inhabitants are divided into dominant "hard ones" and subject "soft
>   ones", whereof the latter have three sexes with fixed roles for each
>   sex:
>
> - Rationals (or "lefts") are the logical and scientific sex; identified with masculine pronouns and producing a form of sperm.
> - Emotionals (or "mids") are the intuitive sex; identified with the feminine pronouns and provide the energy needed for reproduction.
> - Parentals (or "rights") bear and raise the offspring, but are identified with masculine pronouns.
>
> All three 'genders' are embedded in sexual and social norms of
>   expected and acceptable behavior. All three live by photosynthesis;
>   whereas sexual intercourse is accomplished by bodily collapse into a
>   single pool (known as 'melting'). Rationals and Parentals can do this
>   independently; but in the presence of an Emotional, the "melt" becomes
>   total, which causes orgasm but also results in unconsciousness and
>   memory loss. Only during such a total "melt" can the Rational
>   "impregnate" the Parental, with the Emotional providing the energy.
>   The hard ones regulate much of soft one society, as by allocating one
>   of each sex to a mating group, called a "triad", and acting as mentors
>   to the Rationals. Little is shown of "hard one" society; wherefore the
>   Emotional Dua, the protagonist of this section of the book, suspects
>   that the "hard ones" are a dying race, retaining the "soft ones" as a
>   replacement for their absent children. This is dismissed by Odeen, the
>   Rational of Dua's triad, who having the most contact with the "hard
>   ones", has heard the "hard ones" speak of a new "hard one" called
>   "Estwald", accounted of exceptional intelligence.

The novel won both the Nebula and Hugo awards (in 1972 and '73, respectively) and is widely considered one of the "must reads" in science fiction.

Comment: Strange as they were the aliens, I found they were Asimov's most "human" protagonists that he ever wrote about (including all of the humans that he even described in his books -main characters or not-, and who usually had the empathy of an industrial robot).