# Short Story about a Malevolent Plane/Dimension

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I've been looking for this short story for the past couple of days. I definitely remember reading sometime in the last 4 years. It involves a dimension or plane of existence trying to breach into ours and it breaks down our normal physics or mathematics or something similar

Comment: This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: You indicated you read this in the last four years. Does that mean you believe it was also written in the last four years?  Or, could it be older?  While somewhat vague, the plot line of destroying our universe could be the A.E Nourse short story "Tiger by the Tail" which has a link here:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95554/short-story-about-a-hole-to-another-universe-that-pulls-in-metal/95556#95556

Comment: @ZohebSatta You say "short story", but could it also have been a novella, novelette or short novel? If so, "Sapphire and Steel" by P.J. Hammond might be it, though it's a long shot as the breakdown of physics goes as far as supernatural events occuring. If this were a full-length novel, I'd suggest "The Gods Themselves" by Isaac Asimov.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found it. It was a pair of tales on the SCP website. Namely: [CASE COLOURLESS GREEN](http://www.scp-wiki.net/case-colourless-green) and [Your Last First Day](http://www.scp-wiki.net/your-last-first-day).

For anyone wondering, the SCP Foundation is a website hosting many fan stories that make up the universe of the the SCP Foundation. The Foundation is a secret global organization that works in the shadows to protect the world from all things alien, mystical, lovecraftian or down right wierd. Their creed is in the name **S**ecure **C**ontain **P**rotect

Answer (score 3):

There's no other dimension or malevolence in there, but the "breaking up of our mathematics" happens in *Luminous* by Greg Egan (1995). Could this be what you're looking for?

In the story, it is actually *us* that unwittingly tap into the "outer plane" (which is conterminous to ours), harrying its inhabitants - who retaliate in self-defense.

Comment: No I don't think that's it, but it definitely looks like a good read.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [*The Gods Themselves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gods_Themselves) by Asimov?

> The main plot-line is a project by those who inhabit a parallel universe (the para-Universe) with different physical laws from this one. By exchanging matter from their universe—para-Universe—with our universe, they seek to exploit the differences in physical laws. The exchange of matter provides an alternative source of energy to maintain their universe. However, the exchange will likely result in the collapse of the Earth's Sun into a supernova, and possibly even turning a large part of the Milky Way into a quasar. There is hope among those in the para-Universe that the energy explosion does happen in our universe.

Comment: I've edited in a basic description from the link of this work but it would be best if you could expand on that to explain how this matches the OP's description.