# Looking for the title of a story with a shoplifter gathering items for beings in another universe via a portal hidden in a bag

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for the title/author of a science fiction short story I read in an anthology many years ago.

From what I remember the story involved a small portal to another universe being discovered inside the lip of a bag, perhaps a purse, when a shoplifter is caught putting items into the bag. The shoplifter seems to be unaware of what they're doing. The story involves scientists investigating the portal, believing that items are being taken in order to collect information about our world, and culminates in a tug of war of an iron bar or some such passing through the portal. The implication that the side winning the tug of war eventually puts stress on the loser's universe in some catastrophic way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's "[Tiger by the Tail](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56224)" by Alan E. Nourse.

The pocketbook shows up on the second page of the story shown here.

[image]

You can read it online in the Internet Archive's copy of the November 1951 [Galaxy Magazine](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1951-11/page/n1/mode/2up).

Also the answer to this old question: [Short story about a hole to another universe that pulls in metal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95554/28516)