# Short story where a woman steals kettles, pots, and pans in a purse that can't possibly fit them

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a classic story and I'm ashamed not to remember the name; unfortunately I haven't been able to remember enough unique details to find it either.

The story begins with a security person at a store watching a woman shoplifting pots and kettles and such, basically anything metal.  What's particularly odd is that her purse can't possibly fit all that she's putting into it.  When confronted she seems genuinely unaware of what she's been doing, and her purse appears to be empty.

Examining her purse reveals a metal band inside the top holding it open.  Anything metal put in it disappears, anything not metal is rejected.

The purse is taken by the military to a lab for study; one of the experiments is to partially feed in an I-beam and try to pull it back out.  The experiment fails because whatever is on the other side of the hole is stronger than anything they can hook up to it.

I don't recall how the story ends, or if there are other collecting devices like this elsewhere in the world.

I would have read this in the 1980s, but I'm sure it was much older, probably 1950s or 1960s.

Comment: [Tiger by the Tail](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95554/short-story-about-a-hole-to-another-universe-that-pulls-in-metal). Organic Marble IDed it last time so I guess they should get the credit this time too :-)

Comment: @jeffronicus While I agree that the question is a duplicate, we don't close those here until the questioner acknowledges the duplication. I'm sure DavidW will do so shortly.

Comment: *Fifty Short Science Fiction Tales* strikes again!  I _really_ must find a copy.  I accept "Tiger by the Tail" is the correct answer, but if anyone wants to write up a _proper_ answer (with quotes, and not just 3 lines) I'll set this as the dupe target.

Comment: It is the Minimum Necessary Answer that I strive for. *Proper* is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @OrganicMarble "Minimum necessary" shouldn't require me to go to the Internet Archive; the answer should be here, not at a link.