What was the short story about a woman stealing aluminum items and putting in a seemingly bottomless shopping bag?
This story came from an anthology, I'm pretty sure. I read it about 30 years ago. A lady ... in somewhat of a trance ... gets caught shoplifting and all she is stealing is aluminum items. The stuff goes into her bag and basically disappears.  When scientists (I think) try to shove something steel into the bag it is immediately shoved back out.

The story is Tiger by the Tail by Nourse. This has already been answered here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/95554/28516  If you agree, please comment saying so.

What happens is scientist attach a hook to something with a VERY power crane, and after its lowered in, start pulling it back out... When suddenly it starts getting pulled back in with even more force.
