# 1970s novel, planetary world with 3 gender species, prohibited inter-species procreation

Tags: story-identification, novel

In the novel, individuals of the three genders are initially prohibited from mating with each other. When they do mate a fourth gender individual is the result. Two of the three genders are bureaucrats, thinkers/builders.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This question is very terse at the moment.  Perhaps you could look at the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for questions to see if it jogs any additional details you could [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/206945/edit) into your question.

Comment: It's a bit confusing the way you talk about "3 gender species." Are you saying that each species was all one gender, and that somehow members of this single gender could reproduce among themselves without needing any other genders? (If so, that seems to be using a strange definition of what a "gender" is.) But are you also saying that the different species/genders could also mate with each  other and produce fertile offspring that way?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95471/story-about-machines-generating-energy-with-parallel-universes-endangering-ours

Answer (score 13):

### [The Gods Themselves](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/41821.The_Gods_Themselves) by Isaac Asimov

Published in 1972, the middle third of the book features an alien species from a parallel reality with three genders: Rationals, Emotionals, and Parentals.  Reproduction among these aliens involves one of each type merging together into a single individual with a distinct personality.