# Novel about dimensional alien goo

Tags: story-identification, novel, novella

An older male researcher and a younger female researcher (a strange relationship develops here with the age gap and power dynamic) are working on some dimensional rift (maybe on a moon base) trying to bridge the gap between our dimension and a neighboring one.

Meanwhile, the book also shows the perspective of several characters (sapient alien 'goos') in this other dimension that are also studying dimensional rift stuff and trying to accomplish the same thing by bridging the gap to our dimension.

The "human chapters" of the book were pretty standard sci-fi affair if I recall correctly, but the "sentient goo chapters" are extremely esoteric and contain some bizarre "sex" (mind-meld) scenes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you are trying to remember [*The Gods Themselves*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gods_Themselves) by Isaac Asimov.

The "human chapters" involve an older physicist working on a way to get access to energy from parallel universes.  The Earth already has a way to get energy from one universe, but this guy figures that if it goes on long enough the Sun will go nova.

The energy transfer was started by the characters in the other universe.  As long as Earth operates their transfer station(s), the aliens can collect energy.  If the Earth stations shutdown then the aliens will run out of energy.  It is to their advantage if our sun goes nova because then they could tap into its energy without any help.

The old guy works together with a young woman on the moon.  He has been basically blacklisted because he disagrees that the energy transfer is all good - he can't get a job at any university or research institute on the Earth.  He has ideas that he can put into operation with relatively little equipment, and he figures he can get access to what he needs in a laboratory on the moon (which is independent from the Earth.)  The folks on the moon can't operate an energy transfer station - it requires cooperation with the aliens, and they don't show any interest in connecting with the moon.

There is no communication between the two sides.  The aliens have a way to let a small amount of their universe "leak" into our universe.  That changes the nuclear forces in a way such that a normally stable metal (tungsten) changes to a radioactive isotope of plutonium, which can be used to generate electricity.  The first exchange was mostly accidental - if the material hadn't been recognized in our universe there would have been an explosion.

By letting some of their universe leak over into ours, some of our universe leaks back into the aliens' universe.  That modifies some aspect of something there that can be used for energy.

There is mention of "strange alien sex" because the aliens have three sexes - it takes three of them to "melt" and have a baby.  The aliens aren't goo, but they can pass through rock (if they want to) even though it is taboo.  When "melted," the three alien partners turn into one "hard one" - a single being with properties much like a human.  They can't pass through rocks.  All of the alien scientists are "hard ones."  Eventually, each partnership manages to stay "melted" and be a "hard one" for the rest of its life.  The three sexes aren't aware of this final stage while they are still immature.

There's no "goo," but the rest fits.

---

If this is the story you have in mind then it is a duplicate of [this question.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95471/story-about-machines-generating-energy-with-parallel-universes-endangering-ours)

Comment: i read that book long ago. the goo thing sounded wrong but i think u cleared it up. a very sophisticated story, at least when i was 10 or so. way too much for me come to think of it.

Comment: It's a good story.  Maybe too much for a ten year old, but you might want to read it again.

Comment: I am optimistic that as an adult I would have a chance. The worst thing about rereading stories I liked as a kid is being disappointed not infrequently.  Can't think of examples, but sadly fiction itself does not work that well for me -- this may be common among adults, I do not know. I sure enjoy history and biography much more than fiction nowadays.

Comment: This is the answer.  Thank you! I think the "melting" and "soft ones" left a general gooey impression on my brain.